# Scale geometry to real world

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to scale my geometry to fit a real world scaling onto my 3D scene.
I get the top left corner of my map and the top right corner of my map.
I then convert those to points using the Google maps projection and then subtract those points from each other to get the delta of the map.
Then I use that number and divide it by my geometries bounding box deltaX.
The problem is that the code doesn't produce a right scaling.
The more I zoom into the map, the smaller the scaling gets and the more I zoom out, the larger to scaling gets. It should be the opposite.
I also don't know if this is actually scaling it correctly as it would be in real life.

Right now I do this:

```javascript
var bounds = MAP3D.map.getBounds();
var projection = MAP3D.map.getProjection();

var x1Length = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(new google.maps.LatLng(
    bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    bounds.getSouthWest().lng()
));
var x2Length = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(new google.maps.LatLng(
    bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
));
var ThreeUnitsX = Math.abs(x2Length.x - x1Length.x);


if (
    MAP3D.ObjectManager.WellList[i].LOD.objects[0]
        .object.geometry.boundingBox == null
) {
    MAP3D.ObjectManager.WellList[i].LOD.objects[0]
        .object.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
}

var boundingBox = MAP3D.ObjectManager.WellList[i].LOD.objects[0]
    .object.geometry.boundingBox;

var deltaX = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
var scaleX = ThreeUnitsX / deltaX;

me.WellList[i].LOD.scale.set(scaleX, scaleX, scaleX);
```

<sub>I want to thank `chandlerp` from the `#THREE.JS` irc for helping me a lot.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
var scaleX = ThreeUnitsX / deltaX;
```

should be

```
var scaleX = deltaX / ThreeUnitsX ;
```

But that is only correct if your object should always be 111km long.